# How can I exclude a field from my query when the related variable is empty?

Tags: javascript, mongodb

I'm trying to create a function that queries MongoDB based on multiple different field values, where some of them might be just an empty string. When a field is just an empty string, I'm trying to have MongoDB just ignore that part of the query.

My query function looks like this:

```
function GetReports(args) {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        MongoClient.connect(url, function (err, db) {
            if (err) throw err;
            var dbo = db.db(args.organization);
            dbo.collection("reports").find(
                {
                    "name": { 
                        $regex: "(?i)" + args.query + "(?-i)" 
                    }, 
                    "project_number": { 
                        $regex: "(?i)" + args.project_number + "(?-i)" 
                    }, 
                    "category": args.category
                }).sort( { "date_sent": -1 }).skip(fetchedDocPerCall * (page - 1)).limit(fetchedDocPerCall).toArray(function (err, result) {
                if (err) reject(err);
                db.close();
                resolve(result);
            });
        });
    });
}
```

As you can see, I'm trying to find documents which regex match the field "name" or "project_number", while perfectly matching the category field. The issue is that any of the fields from the args argument can be empty, which is when I want MongoDB to just ignore that part of the query, instead of actually looking for fields where the field is an empty string. I could always just create tons of different functions for each permutation, but I was hoping there is a way to just have a single query function?

Comment: Start with a key array like `["query", "project_number", "category"]` and filter it based on whether `args[key]` is empty. Then create your match object based on the remaining keys using `.map()`

Comment: Did you try using a ternary operator. If say args.query != "" ? "(?i)" + args.query + "(?-i)" : ""

Comment: @ChrisG Yeah, I didn't even consider that I can just use the query object as a variable. Thanks for tip.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based in @Cris G suggestion, you would have something like this:

```
function GetReports(args) {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    MongoClient.connect(url, function (err, db) {
      if (err) throw err;
      var dbo = db.db(args.organization);
      const mapping = {
        query: "name",
        project_number: false,
        category: false,
      };
      const match = {};
      for (const [field, alias] of Object.entries(mapping)) {
        if (field in args && args[field] !== "") {
          Object.assign(match, {
            [alias || field]: args[field],
          });
        }
      }
      dbo
        .collection("reports")
        .find(match)
        .sort({ date_sent: -1 })
        .skip(fetchedDocPerCall * (page - 1))
        .limit(fetchedDocPerCall)
        .toArray(function (err, result) {
          if (err) reject(err);
          db.close();
          resolve(result);
        });
    });
  });
}
```

Comment: just pointing out that in the question "name" was matched with "args.query" and not "args.name"

Comment: I changed a little the solution to map the property names that can be changed.